# How to disable vue-cli adding [if IE] tags to my html output?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-pwa

I'm in a vue-cli created project.

I have an icon reference in my public/index.html file which is intended for android phones.

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/img/icons/touch-icon-192x192.png">
```

But after the application builds, the output is:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/img/icons/touch-icon-192x192.png"><![endif]-->
```

How do I prevent vue-cli, or the vue-pwa-plugin from adding any "if IE" tags to my output?

Comment: Please provide your full steps to reproduce this

Comment: [This](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/c8e64507ba8ef2d6e8620346a83253377cecd3ba/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa/lib/HtmlPwaPlugin.js#L62-L65) is where it gets added by the PWA plugin.

Comment: Would being able to change the icons in [the manifest](https://cutt.ly/PtQHgaw) help? Otherwise, if none of the [default icons](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/c8e64507ba8ef2d6e8620346a83253377cecd3ba/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa/lib/HtmlPwaPlugin.js#L45) can work for you, I think you might need to create a PR or issue on the vue-cli project. I looked up whether you can remove taps from a webpack hook because the IE comment is added by a tap, but it [looks](https://github.com/webpack/tapable/issues/109) like that isn't possible.

Comment: Oh, if that's the case, it makes me sad. I'd prefer to not use a workaround, but just remove the deprecated IE tags all together. I'll wait a few days, and then probably create an issue on the vue-cli project.